# Set specific classes to Material UI component

Tags: material-ui

I have a Link component from Material-UI. 
I make a list of these Link components and want to set a very specific `class` to them, but they always seem to add some extra ones as well

```
import React from "react";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "@material-ui/core";

interface Props {
  to: string;
  children: React.ReactNode | string;
}

const LocalLink: React.FC<Props> = ({ to, children}) => (
  <Link to={to} component={RouterLink} className="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"}>
    {children}
  </Link>
);

export default LocalLink;
```

However, the resulting anchor element has these classes

```
<a class="MuiTypography-root MuiLink-root MuiLink-underlineHover MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button MuiTypography-colorPrimary" href="/">
```

So you see the extra "MuiTypography-root", "MuiLink-root", "MuiLink-underlineHover" and "MuiTypography-colorPrimary".
I guess that Link component adds these, but how can I prevent this?

Also, the class names that I set are passed to the first child of the anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when made a component to handle internal and external links.

```
// import both Link components

import { Link } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
```

Then inside your component, this is the code I use to render the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`

```
// wrap RouterLink with Material UI link and add Mui classes to className

  <Link >
    <RouterLink className="MuiTypography-root MuiLink-root MuiLink-underlineHover  MuiListItem-root MuiListItem-gutters MuiTypography-colorPrimary" to={to}>{value}</RouterLink>
  </Link>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, but I have switched to Ant Design months ago and haven't looked back.

Comment: I had the same feeling of wanting to switch to something else. Wish we had the luxury of time. Thanks Ant Design looks really nice.